# How to get lists of string entries of a list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I wonder how I can make lists of every string entry of a list? Let's say I have a list:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and I want to get automatically a list of every entry of the list above:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is there something you don't understand about the answers there? Use a dictionary, don't create "variable variables". Otherwise [edit] to clarify why you want to do this and what you still want to know.

Comment: Note now you've accepted an answer that was also on the duplicate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do that using a dictionary.

```
vars = {}
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i in list_1:
    if i not in vars:
        vars[i] = []
```

So your `vars` dict will be

```
vars = {
    'a': [],
    'b': [],
    'c': []
}
```

And then you can access to data like a normal variable:

```
>>> vars['a'].append(10)
>>> vars
{'a': [10], 'b': [], 'c': []}
>>> vars['a']
[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to achieve something similar. Just use the names of your strings as dictionary keys and value as a list. `

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict1 = {}
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    dict1[list_1[i]] = [10,20]

print(dict1)
```

which gives you

```
{'a': [10, 20], 'c': [10, 20], 'b': [10, 20]}
```